# Is It Possible to Hide Google Sheet From Selected Users?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Simple question really. Is it possible to hide certain sheets in a Google Sheet Doc from specific editors? The scenario is that each user has a page in which they fill in data. Only they can change data on their page based on sheet protection. For aesthetic purposes and ease of use, I'm trying to find out whether I can hide all sheets except the one the user has permission to edit.

Answer (score 1):

**Unfortunately it is not possible because if you hide or show a sheet - it will apply for anyone who opens it.**

- You can write a script that will show a certain sheet - depending on the user who opened the spreadsheet, but if another user opens the same spreadsheet simulateneously - this will lead to conflict behavior.
- As a workaround, I can recommend you to create a different spreadsheet for every user plus a master spreadsheet to which all the separate spreadsheets will be synched with [=IMPORTRANGE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=en)
- In this scenario, you as the only master spreadsheet editor will have access to all data, while the users have only permissions for their spreadsheet
- Another workaround would be to implement sheet protections (this is different from hiding sheets!).
- In this case, every user can only edit the sheet he is entitled to, but he can still view the other sheets.